# bare non-boolean variables in if statement logic test

Tags: c++, if-statement, variables

My question is how can a random variable be reffered as a logic with satisfied conditions?

Here is an example code:

```
int main()
{
    if ("Hello"){
        cout<<"I don't get it"<<endl;
    }
    if(58){
        cout<<"Neither that"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Non-zero is considered as true and zero is considered as false.

Comment: Non-zero is considered as true, zero as false.   For pointers, zero is a null pointer.   For arrays, the test is of a pointer to its first element (which, for a string literal will never be a null pointer).    So `if ("Hello")` is equivalent to `if (&("Hello"[0] != nullptr)` and `if (58)` is equivalent to `if (58 != 0)``.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Because the standard says so.

`if` statements are implicitly `bool` contexts and will attempt to trigger an automatic conversion to `bool` wherever possible (including if you have a custom class with an `explicit operator bool()`).

String literals are convertible to `const char*`, and all pointers are implicitly convertible to `bool` with a value of `true` when they are nonnull, or `false` when null.

Similarly all integral values are convertible to `bool` with a value of `true` when nonzero, or `false` when zero.

---

It's worth noting that the examples don't really make any sense. In particular, code like this is almost never seen in practice because the branches will be *unconditional*:

```cpp
if ("Hello"){ ... }
if (58){ ... }
```

Usually developers will use `if` statements to test if a *variable* contains some "truthy" value -- e.g.

```cpp
if (some_int) { ... }
if (some_c_string) { ... }
```

Which is just short-hand for an equivalent check, such as:

```cpp
if (some_int != 0) { ... }
if (some_c_string != nullptr) { ... }
```

Both code snippets should produce identical assembly in either case, so it's *mostly* just a stylistic preference (with the one exception being if a user defines a custom conversion to `bool`, which may otherwise be cheaper than an equivalent equality check).